# CSS color property not changing text color?

Tags: html, css

Just like it says, the color property is not changing the color of the text.

The HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/money.html">Money</a></li>
      <li><a href="/sports.html">Sports</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar li {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-nav.c.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 37px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have apply color to your `<a>` tag. Find the below change

```
#navbar li a{
   color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing this morning

Comment: you don't need to add li you can just use `#navbar a`

Comment: Of course you do that unless you don't use any '<a>' in your nav which will affect the all.

Comment: since it is not correct to use `<a>` als `<ul>` child you no not need to add LI

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the anchor (`a`) elements inside the `li`'s.

Try `#navbar li a`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
a:link {  }
a:visited {  }
a:hover { }
a:active {  }
```

possibly with referenz to your navbar if you use multiple links on your site

Answer (score 0):

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rwjdh7yq/3/)

[image]

```
#navbar {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navbar li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none; /*apply list-style to li*/
    text-align: center;/*here we are telling LI to `text-center` all child anchor */
}
#navbar a {
    background-image: url(https://d3ui957tjb5bqd.cloudfront.net/uploads/2013/05/firelight-logo-preview-1-f-560x372.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 60px; /* use padding instead of width and height since you don't know how long the text will be */
}
```